# MemoryStream must be explicitely be disposed?

Tags: .net, dispose, memorystream

As MemoryStream is an unmanaged resource does it always have to be disposed?

Given:

```
1) A method is invoked.
2) A MemoryStream object is created (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();).
3) An exception occurs and is caught from the invoking classes.
```

The reference on the MemoryStream object is therefore lost. Does this scenario need a try/finally-block (or using-statement)?

Comment: Just wanted to say Bonobo is awesome.

Answer (score 20):

In general, all disposable objects must always be disposed.

However, `MemoryStream` doesn't actually need to be disposed, since it doesn't have any unmanaged resources.  (It's just a `byte[]` and an `int`)
The only reason it's disposable in the first place is that it inherits the abstract `Stream` class, which implements `IDisposable`.

Note that *every* other stream must be disposed.

Comment: Disagree that you shouldn't call Dispose in this instance, while it may not be "needed" the fact is that it implements the IDisposable interface and should be called either via using or try/catch/finally because the implementation details could in theory change at some point and since you neglected to honor the interface you could get bit by a bug which could have been avoided

Comment: @Aaron: In this particular case, that's **highly** unlikely.

Comment: Agreed...but it's about making behaviors habitual. People who don't use their turn signal because no cars are around are consciously thinking about the action; it is no longer a habitual behavior and they will at some point forget.

Comment: @Aaron. Yes.  That's why I said _in this particular case_.

Comment: To add a late note: I'm going to venture a guess that `MemoryStream` implements `IDisposable` only because it necessarily derives from `Stream` which implements `IDisposable`. From the reference source, it does seem like perhaps `MemoryStream`'s base uses some 'async IO resources' as the reference source calls it that could maybe be disposed, but the base `Dispose` is completely empty right now.

Comment: In addition - if you don't Dispose the MemoryStream - it will raise eyebrows for fellow developers who in turn will probably end up in this thread :) adding Dispose will save some time for them

Answer (score 4):

Any type that implements `IDisposable` should have `Dispose` called on it either explicitly via a try/catch/finally block or via the using statement.

There are cases such as this where technically the `MemoryStream` does not need disposed, however to honor the interface and protect yourself from changes downstream `Dispose` should still be called.

Answer (score 1):

`MemoryStream` implements `IDisposable` so when possible, use a using statement.

When that isn't feasible, make it a try/catch/finally block.

In cases when you need to let the object pass out of the scope of your code (when using or try/catch/finally won't work), it becomes the responsibility of the caller to implement the explicit disposal.

Answer (score -1):

See here [Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx)

Looked at the IL and `using` does this:

```
try
{
}finally
{
((System.IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
}
```

Which means your stream will get disposed no matter what but the exception(if it occurs in 
the try block) will remain on the stack so it may crash you app if you don't take care.

**So:
"The reference on the MemoryStream object is therefore lost. Does this scenario need a try/finally-block (or using-statement)?" - Its the same**

Now its really interesting what would happen if the Dispose method fails for some reason-
you got an IE security hole:) Kidding:)