# Dispose a memory stream from a argument out

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream

I have code for which MemoryStream does not disposes the value.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
string result = RandomFunction(out ms, string input) //the stream value is generated inside the Randomfunction
// Some code which uses the bytes of ms stream
ms.Close()
```

So even after Closing the stream. The variable ms does not dispose the value. Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `MemoryStream` class a `Dispose` method is empty

Comment: Why not let the Garbage Collector do its job?

Comment: As it creates an issue of memory leakage and even by using the using() statement does not disposes the value.

Comment: Read this answer and see if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195746/memorystream-must-be-explicitely-be-disposed

Comment: `Close` and `Dispose` are synonyms, and `using` **will** call `Dispose`. So whatever symptoms you're experiencing, they are *not* related to the absence of `Dispose`. Note that disposal and garbage collection are distinct concepts. If you're experiencing a memory leak, you need to obtain a profiler or a memory dump and trace the GC Roots that are keeping objects alive longer than you believe they should be.